# asignar varias clases a un estilo

Tags: html, css

estoy armando una página y estoy utilizando las hojas de estilo [w3.css](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp) y resulta que me gustaría asignar a todos los elementos "a" las mismas 4 clases quedando cada elemento definido de la siguiente forma:

```html
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-border-bottom w3-border-deep-purple" style="text-align:right;">Usuario</a>
```

como esto me parece muy repetitivo me gustaría hacer algo del estilo:

```css
a {
  w3-bar-item;
  w3-button;
  w3-border-bottom;
  w3-border-deep-purple;
}
```

Pero claramente esto no funciona, ¿hay alguna manera de hacer algo así o queda como una fantasía?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una cosa son los estilos css y otra muy distinta los selectores (clases), las clases o selectores sirven para identificar un objeto, en este caso "a", no puedes incluir clases y tratar de que funcionen como estilos, para eso tienes que agrupar los estilos css que contiene cada clase y agruparlas en una sola, luego adjudicarla al objeto "a".

```
.w3-bar-item {padding:8px 16px;float:left;width:auto;border:none;display:block;outline:0}
.w3-button {border:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;color:inherit;background-color:inherit;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-border-bottom {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important}
.w3-border-deep-purple,.w3-hover-border-deep-purple:hover {border-color:#673ab7!important}
```

Ahora, considero que es demasiado css para un simple enlace, aparte que muchos estilos se contradicen, no se si es por el mal uso de las clases de parte de W3 o estás eligiendo clases al asar, si vas a usar un framework lo recomendable es apegarte a el, o crear estilos desde cero, asi como deseas solo lograrás escribir demasiado código repetitivo que al final afectará el renderizado de tu página. además muchas clases de los frameworks están ligadas a otras `clases, pseudoelementos, hover, before,` etc.

Checa la diferencia abajo en ambos enlaces, uno con las clases solicitadas, y otra totalmente custom y sin uso de css.

```css
/* primer botón (w3.css)*/
.btn01 {
  padding:8px 16px;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  border:none;
  display:block;
  outline:0; 
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  background-color:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc!important; 
  border-color:#673ab7!important
}

/* segundo botón (custom)*/
.btn02 {
  padding:8px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom:1px solid #673ab7;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn01" style="text-align:right;">Usuario</a>

<a class="btn02">Usuario</a></div>
```